# React Native Show <View> using Loop

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

Is there a way using "View" to make it loop?
I have already tried using:

```
function generateListViewPager (shapeStyle) {
    return () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.pageContainer} >
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                for(let i = 0; i < 40; i++){
                    <View style={[styles.shapeBase]}>
                        <Image
                            style={{width: windowWidth, height: 260, alignItems: 'center'}}
                            source={{uri: 'https://test.com/img/i.jpg'}}
                        />
                        <View style={{
                            position: 'absolute',
                            width: windowWidth - 15,
                            height: 130,
                            bottom: 41,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
                        }}>
                            <Text style={styles.TitleStyle}>Test i</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.subButton}>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.hairline} />
                        <View style={styles.subContent}>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I need to show my view from 0 to 39, how would I do it using a loop? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating javascript with your `for` loop but you don't have the curly braces around it. I think you could wrap your repeating component into a [dumb component](https://medium.com/.../dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43):

```
const MyRepeatedView = ({ i }) => {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.shapeBase]}>
            <Image
                style={{width: windowWidth, height: 260, alignItems: 'center'}}
                source={{uri: 'https://test.com/img/i.jpg'}}
            />
            <View style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                width: windowWidth - 15,
                height: 130,
                bottom: 41,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
            }}>
                <Text style={styles.TitleStyle}>Test {i}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.subButton}>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.hairline} />
            <View style={styles.subContent}>
            </View>
        </View>            
    );
};

function generateListViewPager (shapeStyle) {
    return () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.pageContainer} >
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                {[...Array(40).keys()].map(i => <MyRepeatedView key={i} i={i} />)}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, it worked thank you
Using : {[...Array(40).keys()].map(i => <MyRepeatedView i={i} key={i} />)}

save problem warning child

Comment: ah yes, including the key prop also helps with performance, i'll update my answer

Comment: This version run on iOS only, but when I try using at Android the content is not show up @joshweir

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using a `Flatlist` component.

Check documentation here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html